Advice for clean upgrade to 24.04 from 23.10 with RAID1 using mdadm
Looking for advice on how to to a clean install / upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 on a desktop computer I use for streaming/Plex that also has 2x12 TB (Ext4) drives in RAID1 configuration using mdadm.
Currently I have Ubuntu & Windows 11 dual boot but plan on only using Ubuntu and install on the 512GB SSD HD -- considering on using BTRFS instead of Ext4.
Will Ubuntu be able to recognize the RAID drives?
Is there some backup of config files that I ought to do?
Are there any other considerations I ought to be aware of?
I'm no Linux expert but am comfortable with CLI/Bash.  Any advice much appreciated.

Have you read the release notes of the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, as issues encountered in Quality Assurance testing & required mitigation details are found there. Next is the NobleUpgrades & other upgrade document that was listed in release announcements.  I've assumed you've boot your system with 24.04 live media, so as to see on your own hardware how your system deals with the newer kernel (and kernel modules)...   You can even use daily ISOs if you want an upgraded system (since 24.04 is a LTS release & dailies are still created for later (24.04.1) releases)

This question is similar to: How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
